# I am getting INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE while trying to run android project with native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb, native

trying to run an android app. with native code in it. And I have the ndk set up . but I am getting INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE as error in console while running it on my device.

can any1 help me with this?

thanks in advance

Comment: please google with keyword INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE , hope you will get something

Comment: Your project has NDK code that is not compiled to match the CPU architecture of your device. What is your device, and what CPU architectures does your NDK app support?

Comment: device is samsung Y pro using android 2.3.5 Model No: GT-B5510:
and the project im trying to run is the openCV facedetection sample if ur familiar with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galaxy Y has an ARMv6-based CPU, which means you should compile your code with at least 'APP_ABI := armeabi', which is normally the default.

Many recent devices have an ARMv7-based CPU, which runs 'armeabi' and 'armeabi-v7a' binaries, the later run much more efficiently on these devices, but they will not on the Galaxy Y.

It is likely you're using a prebuilt native shared library (e.g. libfoo.so) that was built for 'armeabi-v7a', and the system is complaining that the device cannot run them.

Try rebuilding the library with "APP_ABI := armeabi", you will find more information about this under $NDK/docs/CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html and $NDK/docs/APPLICATION-MK.html.